# Call an external API into a Ruby on Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using a Clear bit gem. How do I call the external API in the Rails application and send data back forth without the default database to store data.I need to build a form like the Clear bit form and send data back and forth.Do I need a controller and model for the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To call any external url, you should require `rest-client` gem.

```
url = "https://...."
body = RestClient.get(url)
JSON.parse(body)
```

You have to check the [rest-client documentation](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client)

Comment: @neilmartis you need to do it using AJAX requests; you'll need to connect to clearbit using $.ajax (javascript code) that calls the rails code which will return the result to the javascript code - then you'll check whether the user's info is returned or not. Check this link for Async Ajax calls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366118/when-to-use-async-false-and-async-true-in-ajax-function-in-jquery and this one to check if the user stopped typing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220126/run-javascript-function-when-user-finishes-typing-instead-of-on-key-up